# Cannot execute code, session has been disposed. Please try restarting the Kernel. ("tensorflow multi gpu")

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, multi-gpu

I'm trying to make this model for you locally but I'm stuck at this step
"warmup_results = multi_gpu_model.predict(train_data.batch(100).take(1))"

it gives me this error

Cannot execute code, session has been disposed. Please try restarting the Kernel.
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.

version of python :  3.10.11
version of tensorflow :  2.10.1
version of cuda :  11.6

Comment: Hi @Abderrahmane RAHMANI, Please try again by installing the `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1` as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu). Let us know if the issue still persists.